# Getting all members of a group and its subgroups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, pentaho, kettle

I have groups as such:

- GroupA

  - GroupB

    - Users

    GroupG

    - Users

So the goal is to get all users that are members of parent group GroupA.

I have the following filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=*MyEmailDomain.com)(memberOf=CN=GroupB,OU=MyOU3,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU1,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL))
```

Which works for the lowest level groups.

From research, it seems that this should work, but doesn't:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=*MyEmailDomain.com)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=GroupA,OU=MyOU3,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU1,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL)))
```

If it matters, I'm using Active Directory Explorer to get the Distinguished Names, and the LDAP Input step in Pentaho's Data Integration tool (Kettle/PDI) to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love the fact that I always find the answer to my questions as soon as I post them somewhere. I need to learn to post much earlier and maybe I will spend less time searching :)

Found a random stackoverflow post that indicated there's an error in the msdn article for this and it has too many parenthesis.

This won't work:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=*MyEmailDomain.com)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=GroupA,OU=MyOU3,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU1,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL)))
```

But this DOES work:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=*MyEmailDomain.com)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupA,OU=MyOU3,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU1,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL))
```

(no parenthesis around the Distinguished Name)

Comment: happens all the time. simply explaining the problem is often enough to make you think differently and find the solution!

Comment: Whad do you set for base to apply this filter?

Answer (score 0):

Hi This does not fetch the users recursively. This is just giving the list of users of parent group only.

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(mail=*MyEmailDomain.com)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupA,OU=MyOU3,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU1,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL))
```